# Python multiplying all even numbers in a list

Tags: python, list, numbers, multiplication

I am working on this python code for my first programming class. Yesterday it partially worked but then I changed something and now it is only passing 1 test case. The goal is to multiply all even numbers in list "xs" and return 1 if there are no even numbers. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

```
def evens_product(xs):
    product = 2
    for i in xs:
        if i%2 == 0:
            product *= i
            return product

    else:
        return (1)
```

Edit: Chepner's solution worked thank you to everyone who helped

Comment: When there *are* even numbers in the list, what is the function meant to return?

Comment: I think starting it at product = 2 is wrong? Shouldn't it be product = 1?

Comment: When even numbers are present the program is supposed to multiply all of the even numbers in the list together and return the final value (for example if the list was [2,4,6,8] it should return 384) and return 1 only when no even numbers are present. Edit: Product = 1 also doesn't work not sure what it should equal

Comment: You haven't shown any of the failing test cases or their output, so it's hard to know what behaviour you expect to see.  I'm guessing that you meant to start with `product = 1`.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your code: the first one is that you start with `product = 2` instead of `product = 1`; the second error is that you should return the answer after you have gone through all the elements of the loop (i.e. after the for loop). At the moment the code returns after it find the first even number. If you follow this approach you wouldn't even need the else statement on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize `product = 1`, for two reasons. One, simply put, you'll get the wrong answer. `evens_product([4])` should return 4, not 8.
Two, it saves you from having to treat a list with no even numbers as a special case. If there are no even numbers, you never change the value of `product` and return it unchanged.

```
def evens_product(xs):
    product = 1
    for i in xs:
        if i%2 == 0:
            product *= i
    return product
```

Comment: The added recursive version makes me reconsider my upvote :-). I think it's worse in every way....

Comment: I took your advice but it's still having issues. For the list [1,2,3,4,5] it is returning 2, when the list is empty it is returning "None" and when no even numbers are present it is returning "None". This is definitely a confusing assignment

Comment: It's definitely worse Python. I probably should have left it as psuedocode.

Comment: @famguy74 You typed something wrong. Neither version would return `None` on any input, and both return `8` for `[1,2,3,4,5]`. (I did fix a few typos in the recursive function, but you shouldn't be using that anyway.)

Comment: @chepner you were right there was something wrong with the formatting or something I started a new file and your solution worked so I selected your answer as the best one

Comment: Deleted the recursive solution. It didn't really help explain anything.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is using the `reduce()` function from `functools` and the `operator.mul()` function.

The `reduce()` function takes a function that takes three arguments (in this case, `operator.mul()`), an iterable (which is a list in this case), and default value.

It applies the function to the first two elements, yielding a result. It takes that result, and applies that function to the result and the third element of the list, then the result of that to the fourth and so on. It repeats this process until all arguments have been iterated through.

In this case, operator.mul() is used to describe the multiplication operation. For example, `operator.mul(2,3)` is 6.

Lastly, you can select even values in a list by using a list comprehension with an `if` clause at the end. If a number `i` is even, the value `i % 2` should be zero, since `%` is the modulus operator, which returns the remainder after the left side is divided by the right.

Here is what an implementation would look like, although you should define behavior for when there are no even numbers, perhaps with `try: except:` blocks.

---

Added default/initial value `1` to avoid error in case of empty list.

```
import functools, operator
def even_product(lst):
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, [i for i in lst if i%2 == 0], 1)
```

Comment: Please add explanation.

Comment: Note that this raises an error if there are no even elements in a list. That behavior should probably be defined unless an even number is guaranteed in every scenario.

Answer (score -1):

This will be your answer:

```
def evens_product(xs):
    product = 1
    for i in xs:
        if i%2 == 0:
            product *= i  
    return product
```

There is no need to `return` `1` since the product is already assigned `1`. 
Since you has the `return` inside the `for` loop it was returning the value after identifying the first even number. Hope it helped.

Comment: Your 'else' clause will never be reached, then, right? I think it is correct if you remove the else clause and initiate product to 1