# multiply even numbers, add odd numbers

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to solve how to multiply all even numbers in a list with 2, and add all odd numbers with 7. And then present the list in an descending order. It has to be with a function that takes the list as argument.

I found this here on stackoverflow, but it's not really what I'm after, since the example sums up the even numbers to one product.

This is my code:

```
L = [45, 22, 2, 498, 78]

def EvenOdd(L):

product = 2
resp = 7
elem = None

for elem, val in enumerate(L):
elem += 1
if elem % 2 == 0:
   product *= elem
if elem % 2 == 1:
   resp += elem
   result = L[elem]
   result.sort()
   result.reverse()
print(result)
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot the link to the example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39835536/python-multiplying-all-even-numbers-in-a-list

Comment: So your problem is that it's too difficult to cheat on your homework because the code snippet isn't exactly what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create new list using:

```
new_list = [item * 2 if item % 2 == 0 else item + 7 for item in L]
```

and then sort it using:

```
new_list.sort(reverse=True)
```

Output should look like this:

```
[996, 156, 52, 44, 4]
```